# Sort dates from JSON in descending order

Tags: android, json, date

I want to sort date in descending order. 
The dates are from json. I parsed it through AsyncTask. But i dont know how to sort the date in descending order. This is my code :

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(EventsActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.d("EventsActvity:data from server",data);

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    Events event = new Events();

                    event.setevent_title(obj.getString("event_title"));
                    event.setstart_date(obj.getString("start_date"));
                    event.setsmall_picture_path(obj.getString("small_picture_path"));
                    event.setend_date(obj.getString("end_date"));
                    event.setstart_time(obj.getString("start_time"));
                    event.setend_time(obj.getString("end_time"));
                    event.setlocation(obj.getString("location"));
                    event.setevent_desc(obj.getString("event_desc"));
                    event.setpicture_path(obj.getString("picture_path"));
                    event.setrequire_registration(obj.getString("require_registration"));
                    event.setevent_id(obj.getString("event_id"));
                    event.setquantity_left(obj.getString("quantity_left"));
                    eventList.add(event);

                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            //return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //return false;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

how to sort the date in descending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Event class must implements the `Comparable` interface. Then, override the `compareTo()` method to sort by date. And finnaly, sort your List with `Collections.sort(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple sol,
it converts date String to time in millseconds, and compare them as Long values
it will insert event object based on comparing its date against the date of the top even object in the list

i used **startDate**, you can change which field you want to use
i used `Vector()`, so i can insert event object on specific index

these changes for the code you already have, its where you parse Json and set values in event object:

```
Vector<Events> events = new Vector<Events>();

        try {
//          System.out.println(sdf.parse("2014-08-17 14:55:22").getTime());
//          System.out.println(sdf.parse("2014-08-17 14:55:23").getTime());
//          System.out.println(sdf.parse("2014-08-17 14:55:24").getTime());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                //parse and init the event bean ...


                //replace eventList.add(event); with:
                if(eventList.size() == 0){
                    //1st item, add it on loc=0
                    eventList.add(event);
                }else{
                    long time = getTimeLong(event.getstart_date);
                    if(time > getTimeLong(events.get(eventList.size()-1).getStartDate())){
                        eventList.add(0,event);//add event at top of list
                    }else{
                        eventList.add(event);//add event at end of list
                    }
                }
             }//for loop

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this method gets time as millseconds

```
private long getTimeLong(String dateTime){
        if(dateTime.trim().equals("")){
            return -1;
        }

        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d H:mm:ss").parse(dateTime).getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

you can also compare dates using `after(Date when)` or `before(Date when)`, at Date object instead of `getTime()` after converting the strings to Date `date1.before(date2)`